# Get posts that created in the past 24hr of a facebook page using php sdk 4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Facebook in versions after 2.0 will not support FQL anymore.
So I've to change from FQL to graph api instead.

My old FQL code is..

```
SELECT source_id,post_id,message,like_info.like_count,comment_info.comment_count,share_info.share_count,permalink,created_time,attachment.media FROM stream WHERE source_id = "--page_id--" AND actor_id = "--page_id--" AND created_time>--time_start-- AND created_time<--time_end-- ORDER BY like_info.like_count DESC
```

and this is my graph api code using phpsdk4 which transfer from the fql code above and it's not complete (because I don't know how to do next step).

```
require_once 'facebookphpsdk4/autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

$access_token = 'xxx|yyy';
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'xxx','yyy' );
$session = new FacebookSession($access_token);
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/page_id?fields=posts{id,shares,message,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true)}'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

I need ....

- permalink's post
- large size images attachment's post
- to filter period of time (created in the past 24 hours)
- to order by (DESC) amount of like or order by created_time

How can I get all of this without using fql ? 
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues about getting the same result with the Graph API instead of FQL:

- There's no `permalink` field
- You can't explicitly specify the `attachments` to be large
- You can't apply an ordering. Default ordering should be by `created_time` though

To specify the time filter, you can use the URL parameters `since` and `until`:

```
GET /{page_id}/posts?fields=id,message,shares,object_id,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true),attachments{media}&since=1423440000&until=1423526399
```

This should giveyou all posts from today for a specific page.

You could create a `permalink` by concatenating imho:

```
https://www.facebook.com/{page_id}/posts/{object_id}
```

See:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post#fields
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#paging

Comment: Thank you for your answer XD. About "permalink" ...I've try to use "actions=>link" instead, it's work on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  but it's not work when I used it in my php code. 

What should I do to get a link to the post ?

Comment: What do you mean with "not work when I used it in my PHP code"? If it's returned by the Graph API, then you have a problem in your PHP script.

Comment: I don't know why it's not work too. I only add 'actions'  parameter (in graph api explorer and in my graph api with phpsdk but it's work only one although i use the same condition). Use object_id must be the easiest way XD thank you again for your kindness that help me a lot.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, @Tobi. I've got some problem with the graph api again.
1. sometimes I've got a post's data which is not exist in the page(and doesn't have post's message. Although I found it has different post's id with another one but it's come from the same src.  I guess It's may be related with some reply of the post.... but how can i fix it ? I don't want it. I just want the post that exist in page (not include reply). [PS.Graph API Explorer and my phpsdk code got the same result]

Comment: 2. I usually got an error  '(#613) Calls to stream have exceeded the rate of 600 calls per 600 seconds.'  although I call it first time of the day (with the same code you gave me). Why ? T_T